# ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE: Web deployment task failed

Tags: iis-7, web-deployment

When I try to publish code using Web Deploy method I am getting the following error

ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE: Web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote computer ("xxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxx.xxxx"). On the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web Management Service") is started

On my server,I have web deployer 3.5 install and web management service is also running.
There is no firewall issue also.
I have restarted the web management service still no luck

Answer (score 0):

If you want to publish a site on a remote server you could follow the below steps:

- Go to the Start menu and right-click the cmd.exe and then select Run as Administrator.
  Enter the following in the command prompt:

  ```
  winrm quickconfig
  winrm set winrm/config/client @{TrustedHosts="*"}
  ```
- On the target server, open a command prompt as an Administrator and
  enter the following:

  ```
  winrm quickconfig
  winrm set winrm/config/client @{TrustedHosts="IP_ADDRESS"}
  ```

where IP address is the IP address of your remote server.

make sure you installed Management service.
[image]

-after doing all the above things open iis.

- create site with a blank folder at the destination (remote server)
- go back to the server from which you want to publish a site and select Publish.
- On the Publish page, click the icon labeled IIS, FTP, etc.
- In the Publish Method list box, select Web Deploy:

[image]

or if you want to publish as an application under any site:

- no need to create site at the destination server.
- enter your site name in the site name and enter your application name after /.
  [image]

Regards,
Jalpa